# User who asks many low quality questions

Tags: discussion, bad-questions, post-ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How did this user amass more than 2k worth of reputation?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3457/how-did-this-user-amass-more-than-2k-worth-of-reputation)

I have seen [this user](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/26782/goma) posting *many* low quality/off-topic questions.

Many of these are getting closed and subsequently deleted.

Out of his 80 questions, about 40 are closed, though there are several that have been highly upvoted (over 5 upvoted). But from the amount of questions asked, it appears to me that it is more by chance that he post some good questions.

I have posted a comment on one of his (now closed) [questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/146296/abstract-comparison-between-three-server-side-languages) asking why he is posting such question, but got no reply.

What can we do about his activity? Should he be post banned?

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3457/how-did-this-user-amass-more-than-2k-worth-of-reputation/3461#3461

Comment: We are well aware of Goma thank you! ;-)

Comment: @maple_shaft - I had no idea. As ChrisF answered, the latest suspension was lifted recently, explaining why I hadn't noticed him before...

Comment: 325 questions in total... you can't even begin to imagine the crap you don't see. I'll close this as a dupe of the earlier Goma discussion, just don't go on a down voting spree (not you Oded, everyone else), last time he made it into Meta three people started downvoting everything and they were caught by the serial voting script.

Comment: @YannisRizos - I can imagine how surprised they were when the script kicked in...

Comment: @YannisRizos your comment looks worth "promotion" to [an answer](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/3526/31260 "promotion done here") doesn't it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The history of Goma is long and tortuous.

Suffice to say that he has been suspended in the past for poor quality questions, sock puppetry and trying to evade previous suspensions. His latest activity comes immediately after the lifting of his latest suspension (for a year), so clearly the normal procedures don't work with him.

Most, if not all, of his reputation comes from questions asked before the low quality filters were implemented so there is little, if not no, chance of him being automatically question banned now.

All the moderators, past and present, have been involved with this - as have several Stack Exchange employees - we are well aware of him and his activities.

Comment: I guess my only question is... what can I do to help? This is one bad apple.

Comment: @Oded - down-vote and vote to close as appropriate when you come across one of his posts in the normal use of the site.

Comment: Already doing this, though I will be less tolerant of his posts from now on and will no longer try to engage him.

Comment: @Oded Flag his questions when you encounter him, downvote and vote to close.  We have merged tens of his accounts into Goma and kept it around for historical significance and perverse curiousity.  It is up in the air what the next step will be.

Comment: Chris, @maple_shaft - could you please check details of a **[slippery undownvote](http://i.stack.imgur.com/o1kqF.jpg "marked WTF at screen shot")** shown in Goma's yesterday rep for a [question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/58840) that 1) has recent activity and 2) was recently closed and 3) is rather heavily downvoted? Without more details I can't tell either it's reasonable or script has gone mad and began to [jeopardize community efforts](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3457/how-did-this-user-amass-more-than-2k-worth-of-reputation/3526#comment9570_3526)

Comment: @gnat - it could be that as it decided some of the votes were serial in nature it invalidated other votes as well. I don't think there's *too* much to worry about here. The community is doing a great job, just exercise a little caution over the frequency of your votes.